# Parsing arguments to functions involving ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having an issue trying to improve the functionality of my ajax functions by adding arguments to define what to do with the returned result.

So what i am trying to implement is a way to tell the function to append the result to a given element by its `id`. But i am having difficulty understanding how to add this functionality.

This is my current code:

```
var ajax = new function(){

    var self = this;

    self.x = function() {
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }
    };

    self.send = function(url, callback, method, data, sync) {
        var x = self.x();
        x.open(method, url, sync);
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4) {
                callback(x.responseText)
            }
        };
        if (method == 'POST') {
            x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        x.send(data)
    };

    self.get = function(url, data, callback, sync) {
        var query = [];
        for (var key in data) {
            query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
        }
        self.send(url + (query.length ? '?' + query.join('&') : ''), callback, 'GET', null, sync)
    };
};
```

I then make an ajax request like so:

```
//get the html file, and then call a function
ajax.get(dir.layout+'login.html',false,
        function(){
            elements.addTemplate(data,'parent',true);
        });
```

In Chrome the xhr shows the correct data and contents, so i know that part works. In my `elements.loadTemplate` function i have these three lines with their actual values:

```
  elements.addtemplate(data,div_id,append){     
      console.log(data); //shows:
      console.log(div_id);   //shows string: parent 
      console.log(append); //shows: true
  }
```

Now the issue is data is blank, when i want it to contain the contents of the HTML file that I just requested (in this case `login.html`). I am wondering why it would show up as blank and how i can fix it?

Comment: FYI: i'm aware of jQuery but, I am trying to learn the vanilla language and how it works, before i use a library.

Comment: where in your code do you expect `data` to contain the HTML of the page you requested. You've shown that `append` is true, which is interesting as there is no variable called `append` in your code. perhaps there's a major issue in the code you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX see edit to see my `elements.addtemplate` function to understand where the var name comes from.

Comment: where does the `data` in `elements.addTemplate(data,'parent',true);` come from?

Comment: Please don't clutter up your code samples with things designed to support IE6 or whatever. MSXML2.XMLHTTP.2.0 hasn't been supported for nearly a decade.

Comment: @torazaburo what are the more recent ones that I should only support?

Comment: @JaromandaX well thats what i am trying to work out how to get to work. I want data to contain the page contents, i put data variable there as that was my attempt to work out how to do it.

Comment: It depends on your browser support requirements. MS supports native XmlHttpRequest since IE7 IIRC. So unless you need to support ancient IE6 machines, it would be preferable to completely remove all the MS-related cruft.

Comment: @torazaburo okay, i have removed it to clean up the code - thanks for explaining that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data is undefined because your callback doesn't accept a parameter

try this:

```
ajax.get(dir.layout+'login.html',false,
        function(data){ // <=== data
            elements.addTemplate(data,'parent',true);
        });
```

Comment: still seems to be blank for me rather than have the contents of login page.

Comment: then you need to see what x.responseText is in your ajax function

Comment: Yup i checked that, it contains the html file contents. .

Comment: Well, I just checked and your ajax code works, and the callback in `ajax.get` receives the data - so, there's something you haven't done quite right

Comment: When you tested it did console.log(data); in a custom function such as my addTemplate function hold the page content?